# Boolean operator, is there a short hand way to do this in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax

I want to do the following:

```
time_heap.insert(aid.arrival(event)!=NULL);
```

ie, insert the returned value of `aid.arrival(event)` to the time_heap if it is not `NULL`.

This is an operation that is going to occur a lot in the main control of my program, and was hoping there is a short-hand way to do it in C++ (aside from defining my own function to handle it)

```
186         void insert_event(Event* value) {
187             heap.push_back(value);               // expand size of heap
188             int i = heap.size() - 1;           // set heap index to that of "value" 
189             int parent = floor((i - 1)/2);
190 
191             while (parent >= 0 && parent < heap.size()) {                //check that parent is valid
192                 if (*heap[parent] > *value) {
193                     heap[i] = heap[parent];
194                     heap[parent] = value;                                // if "value" is smaller than parent move it up in heap (swap)
195                     i = parent;                                         // set new index of "value"
196                     parent = floor((i - 1)/2);                          // set new parent of "value"
197                 }
198                 else                                                  // if parent is not larger, value satisfies min-heap condition (since all below are lower, too)
199                     break;                                                  // (i.e. we are done)
200             }
201         }
```

Comment: Do you want to insert something when the return value is NULL? What type does the `insert` method expect?

Comment: If it's a container of pointers, then it probably expects a pointer.

Comment: What's wrong with your own method for it? It will certainly make it easier for you if you decide to change storage from a heap to something else or add new conditions for insertion at a later point. Don't repeat yourself.

Comment: no, it expects an "Event" back, with parameters like when the event takes place, and what the event is (which are accessed constantly) edit: yes, it is a pointer. sorry. a pointer to a type class Event edit2: Joachim, because i'm not sure that it actually does what I want it to do o.o

Comment: @tadman But how would you know it is a container of pointers? I see nothing in the question to suggest that.

Comment: @user1647959 can you post the signature of `insert`?

Comment: @juanchopanza If the intention is to conditionally `insert` a pointer, it's *probably* a container of pointers. I just read the question where it says "insert the returned value"...

Comment: insert_event is up in the original post

Comment: A few things: 1) If in `Event* value` null is not valid, you should be using a reference: `Event& value`. 2) If you'[re trying to make a heap, C++ already has [functions for that](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=heap&button=). 3) Per your comments below, you should be using smart pointers. Having `new` and `delete` in your code is bad.

Comment: the only pointers are the Event pointers, which are deleted as they are taken of the heap (which I wrote to get more familiar with C++). My understanding is that if I declare Event* a = new Event(x,y,z); then Event* b = a; followed by delete a; then there will be no lingering pointer. Is this correct...?

Answer (score 3):

```
if (Arrival *arrival = aid.arrival(event))
    time_heap.insert(arrival);
```

Comment: It's good that `NULL` is can be presumed to be zero where [this wasn't always the case](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html).

Comment: short hand*       -.- is what I posted invalid syntax? i have to assume it is, but ive got too many things going on in my code right now to compile and check

Comment: @tadman: `NULL` and `0` are convertible to the null pointer, which may or may not be address zero (!).

Comment: yeah I can live with it =p    will this leave a pointer hanging around that i've got to delete?

Comment: @user1647959: What you posted is not invalid *syntax*, but its semantics don't seem to be what you asked for.

Comment: You are responsible for deleting this pointer at some point if the `arrival` method does not claim ownership. Whatever object owns the container should probably do that during in the destructor.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `time_heap.insert(aid.arrival(event)!=NULL);` will not do what you think. The `!=` operator is a boolean one, returning either 0 or 1. So the expression is an integral one, and I doubt your code will compile without error, since insert expects a pointer.
You can probably go with something like

```
if ((Arrival *a = aid.arrival(event)) != NULL)
    time_heap.insert(a);
```

or even

```
if (Arrival *a = aid.arrival(event))
    time_heap.insert(a);
```

Personally I prefer the first option, because of the likelyhood of someone (me) missing the difference between `=` and `==` the next time the code is revised.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able remove the compare with the NULL as NULL is considered to be a 0 value and thus false. Given "x = aid.arrival(event)" you could go with `if(x){time_heap.insert(x);}`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this with my favorite ternary operator? :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

class A {
private:
  int m_i;
public:
  A() : m_i(0) { }
  A(int i) : m_i(i) { }
  int get() const { return m_i; }
  bool operator==(const int i) const { return (m_i==i); }
  bool operator<(const A& other) const { return (m_i<other.m_i); }
};

int main() {
  std::set<A> s;
  A a;
  ( (a = A(42))==42 ? s.insert(a).second : false );
  std::cout << s.begin()->get() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Edit: since people don't like ternary operators, you can achieve something along the lines of what you're asking with C++11 lambdas (or [Boost.Lambda](http://www.boost.org/libs/lambda/)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

class A {
private:
  int m_i;
public:
  A() : m_i(0) { }
  A(int i) : m_i(i) { }
  int get() const { return m_i; }
  bool operator==(const int i) const { return (m_i==i); }
  bool operator<(const A& other) const { return (m_i<other.m_i); }
};

int main() {
  std::set<A> s;
  A a;

  auto f = [&s] (A const& a) { if (a==42) s.insert(a); };

  f(A(42));
  f(A(43));

  std::cout << s.size() << " " << s.begin()->get() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```